# Show a pages code including require statements

Tags: php, html, file

I am trying to display the code of a php file as plain html. This is all going well except for that fact that I would like it to 'open up' the `<?php require 'Main_content_bar.php'; ?>` statements aswell.

So far I have `show_source($page);` correctly working.

It currently prints:

```
<?php require 'Main_content_bar.php'; ?>

<!-- Jumbotron -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Property</h1>

    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus
        commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>

</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Current properties</h2>



    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer">
    <p><a href="Source_code.php" target="_blank"> <img src="Images/codebutton<?php echo $page_lower;?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $page;?> Source"> </img>
        </a></p>

    <p>&copy; Robin B'stards Retail 2014</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

However, as one can see, the contents of the require statements do not show. I cannot for the life of me work out how to do this.

So what it would end up looking like is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>-->
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>-->
    <link href="justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var url = window.location.href;
            var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            $('.nav a[href*="'+page+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="width: 1263px">

    <div class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Ruthless Real Estate</h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li class="menu"><a href="Property.php">Property</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Client.php">Client</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Type.php">Type</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Feature.php">Feature</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Multiple_properties.php">Multiple Properties</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Property_features.php">Property Features</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="Images.php">Images</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- Jumbotron -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Property</h1>

    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus
        commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>

</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Current properties</h2>


    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer">
    <p><a href="Source_code.php" target="_blank"> <img src="Images/codebutton<?php echo $page_lower;?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $page;?> Source"> </img>
        </a></p>

    <p>&copy; Robin B'stards Retail 2014</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Note the lack of require statements

Comment: Can you add the show_source method?

Comment: what do you mean by "open up"? do you want the php code to be partially interpreted (for you case, executing the "require" command, but leaving "echo" ?

Comment: @LoganBailey the function `show_source` is php native ( http://php.net/show_source )

Comment: @Asenar Updated question. This would literally just printed in another pages as plain html. That isn't the problem I'm - just getting the contents of the addition required files aswell to show up.

Comment: Do you have a template rendering engine? I suppose so. The you would use output buffering and wrap the rendered view inside `<pre>` HTML tag o the returned page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with `show_source`, which just "show some code sources" of a file.

You need to create your own function which take a filename in argument, then you have to analyze the source like this:

- replace all require/include/require_once/include_once (what do I forget?) by their own content
- make the function recursive (because Main_content_bar.php can have other include inside it)
- Use [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/highlight_string) at the end of your function.

**EDIT** to search & replace, one way (there is several) is to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all). That part of the code would look like this :

```
$new_content = file_get_contents('your-file.php');
$base_path   = __DIR__.'/';
// pattern to find require, require_once, include, include_once functions
// and catch their arguments
$pattern = "#<\?php (?:require|include(?:_once)?)\s*'(.*)'; \?>#u";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $new_content, $matches))
{
  foreach($matches[0] as $pattern_index => $full_pattern)
  {
    $file = $matches[1][$pattern_index];
    $subcontent = file_get_contents($base_path.$matches[$pattern_index]);
    $new_content = str_replace($new_content, $full_pattern, $subcontent);
  }
}
highlight_string($new_content);
```

Comment: What in built functions would you recommend to search each file for the require statement. Or if that isn't possible what function goes line by line?

Comment: I answered in my post. Note this is a really incomplete solution (require can use parenthesis, or double quote instead of simple quote).

Comment: Where does the $content variable come from. Also you missed a ) after the if statement. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I named the variable `$content`, then I renamed it to `$new_content`.

Comment: So thats what I tried, and it throws:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: match in Source_code.php on line 43
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in Source_code.php on line 43.

It repeats those two lines, which makes me think that its found the 2 relative statements.

Comment: It wasn't $match but $matches (the notice was clear enough ;) . If this still not work, add a print_r($matches) just before the `foreach` and try to debug what's wrong.